# ¿Por qué no esta funcionando el Paginator en un MatTable Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-paginator

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena al consultar el servicio del método `obtenerLista`(), le agregue el MatPaginator pero no esta haciendo nada, no se que me esta haciendo falta para que si haga su función.

en el AppModule ya tengo importado el modulo de MatPaginator

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollme">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar">

              <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" [ngClass]="{
              'text-red': estatus.cveEstado == 'ERR',
              'text-blue': estatus.cveEstado == 'INP'
            }">
                {{ estatus.descripcion }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" type="time" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
              (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'botonSave',
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  horaIngresada: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];
  horaInvalida = true;
  
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
  }

 //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
 changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
  this.horaIngresada = e.value;
  console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
  this.validarHora();
}

validarHora() {
  console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
  const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
  this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
  console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
}


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
  }

  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }

  guardar(element: any) {
    if (element.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = false;

      if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
        alert('No se han modificado campos');
      } else {
        console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
        this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
        this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
          this.fechaIngresada
        );

        console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
        this.controlService
          .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.controlModel = data;
            this.comentIngresado = '';
            this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
            this.fechaIngresada = '';

            alert('Agregado correctamente');
          });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Adicional mi tabla tiene un scroll y al agregar el paginador no sale completo, como puedo hacer que salga el paginador a lo largo de toda la tabla y si se puede alinear de lado izquierdo por que ahorita lo muestra asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debajo de `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` coloca `this.paginator.hidePageSize = false;`, respecto a lo que se apega a la izquierda, en el CSS prueba con `.mat-paginator-container { justify-content: flex-start; }`, si no funciona pon sin el `.`

Comment: agregué esta  linea   this.paginator.hidePageSize = false; pero no hace nada

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que lo tienes en el `ngOninit()`, el cual se ejecuta cuando se inicializa el componente (después del constructor, puedes probar haciendo `console.log` para ver como funciona el ciclo de vida de Angular). Lo que quieres es que después de que tenga los datos se realice la paginación, para eso tienes que usar `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

el cual se activa después de que la vista del componente haya sido inicializada.

[Angular - Component Lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)